# How to add a method to Django class to convert to dictionary

Tags: python, django

I am making a reporting tool for some SW testing...

I have the following model in my models.py file

```
class triage_notes(models.Model):
    stack_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30
    )
    
    build_number = models.IntegerField(    )
    
    fails = models.IntegerField()

    jira_ticket = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    
    notes = models.TextField()
    
    bug_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )
    def as_dict(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {
            "id":self.id,
            "build_number": self.build_number,
            "fails": self.fails,
            "jira_ticket": self.jira_ticket,
            "notes": self.notes,
            "bug_type": self.bug_type
        }
```

As you can imagine, the goal is to be able to use this method in the query call in order to present my query as a dictionary...

In my view I am attempting to use this method

```
def index_view(request):
    context = triage_notes.objects.as_dict()
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

But I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: as_dict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I would love to understand this process better as being able to implement custom methods for my models would be a great tool in the future.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Have a look at [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) if your aim is serialization / making a REST api, etc.

Comment: I appreciate the resource! I will take a look. For the time being, I would still like to learn how to implement this custom method as I believe it would be very valuable to me in the future

Comment: When render html you don't need to transform data in a dict

Comment: @Kurohige - fair enough. To be clear, this app is incomplete... I likely will not be simply rendering this data in HTML, that is just how I have set the code up for testing

Comment: @AustinHallett honestly serialization is a complex task, there are various datatypes you need to handle `int`, `float`, `Decimal`, booleans, dates, datetimes,... and there are multiple formats you can receive these, as such it is simpler to use something that handles these for you. If an extra 3rd party app bothers you, you can also use the builtin serializer with Django as described in the docs: [Serializing Django objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/)

Comment: Well of course solution proposed by @AbdulAzizBarkat it's a great point to start. Anyway it's not clear what do you want to achieve here. specific object? a list of objects? last object?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat - I see your point -- I will take a look at the serialization

Comment: @Kurohige - I see your point. At the moment, I would like to generate a queryset which returns ALL values (hence the lack of a filter) but I realize I did not include the .all() in the query

Answer (score 0):

Django already has [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values) method for queryset which could simplify the job

```
def index_view(request):
    context = list(triage_notes.objects.values("id", "build_number", "fails", "jira_ticket", "notes", "bug_type"))
    print(context)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```